# Trouble aligning Icon and Text inside a Button, using Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, styled-components

I can't align icon and text inside a Button. We have a custom Theme on Material UI that it's overriding the default typograhy and causes this difficulty to align items on the center. When i use the default typography, it aligns properly.

I have tried with this code

```
<Button size={size} color={color}>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '7px', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Icon name='gift' />
          <Typography>Disabled</Typography>
        </div>
</Button>
```

Also.

```
<Button size={size} color={color}>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '7px', alignItems: 'center',lineHeight:'normal'}}>
          <Icon name='gift' />
          <Typography>Disabled</Typography>
        </div>
</Button>
```

It's important to say that with certain font-sizes the icon and text aligned properly.

I add an image to show an example of what's happening.

See the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnr5R.png).

You can see the text it's a bit higher than the icon.

If you have any idea how to solve this , i would appreciate.

Thanks!